# What does this PHP error mean?

Tags: php, mysql

What does the following error message mean?

```
Warning: mysql_data_seek() [function.mysql-data-seek]: Offset 0 is invalid for MySQL result index 3 (or the query data is unbuffered) in \\nawinfs03\home\users\web\b1878\rh.slmarble\php\getproductDB.php on line 6
or die('
```

Code:

```
if (!mysql_data_seek($results, $num)) {
    echo "<h1 style='padding:10%'>Coming soon!</h1>";
}
```

Comment: if you're using this function in web-development, you're doing something wrong

Comment: I don't know your code but I can't think of why you would use the success or failure of a `mysql_data_seek` to determine whether or not some HTML is posted.

Comment: Col. Shrapnel why do you say I'm doing something wrong if I'm using this in web dev?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you're query is returning anything. From the PHP manual:

> ..if the result set is empty
>   (mysql_num_rows() == 0), a seek to 0
>   will fail with a E_WARNING..

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-data-seek.php

Comment: You can suppress the warning by using an `@` in front of `mysql_data_seek(...`.